# WP_Queryで特定の日付以降に該当するデータを取得したい

Tags: wordpress

wp_queryで絞り込み検索機能を実装しています。

イベント記事のカスタムフィールド に「イベント開始日時」「イベント終了日時」のデータがあります。
イベントの日時で絞り込みをかけられる検索機能を作っているのですが、検索機能の日時の条件設定がうまくいきません。

例えば、
「2020/6/20 12:00」と検索したとして、
2020/6/20 12:00以降に開始している or 開始中の記事を取得したいです。

↓の記事はヒットするのですが、
開始日2020/06/20 12:00 ~ 2020/06/21 21:00

こちらの記事がヒットしてくれません。
開始日2020/06/19 11:00 ~ 2020/06/21 21:00

フォームから送信された日時が含まれるものを抽出したいと考えています。

開始日を条件にしているため、開始日がヒットした投稿しか取得ができていないです。

```php
$query = [
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'start_date',
  'order' => 'ASC',
];

if(!empty($_GET['day']) && !empty($_GET['time'])) {
  $date_time = '';
  if(!empty($_GET['day'])) $date_time = $_GET['day'] . ' ';
  if(!empty($_GET['time'])) $date_time .= $_GET['time'];

  if($date_time){
    $query['meta_query'][] = ['key' => 'start_date', 'value' => $date_time, 'compare'=>'>='];
  }
}

$wp_query = new WP_Query($query);
```

### 試したこと

startだけで見ていたので、「start以上、end以下」にしてみました。
すると、

検索　2020/6/20 12:00

取得できた　→　開始日2020/06/19 12:00 ~ 終了日2020/06/21 21:00
取得できない　→　開始日2020/06/30 10:00 ~ 終了日2020/06/30 19:00

```
if(!empty($_GET['day']) && !empty($_GET['time'])) {
  $date_time = '';
  if(!empty($_GET['day'])) $date_time = $_GET['day'] . ' ';
  if(!empty($_GET['time'])) $date_time .= $_GET['time'];

  if($date_time){
    $query['meta_query'][] = [
      'relation' => 'AND',
      ['key' => 'start_date', 'value' => $date_time, 'compare'=>'<='],
      ['key' => 'end_date', 'value' => $date_time, 'compare'=>'>=']
    ];
  }
}
```

`BETWEEN`は使えそうと思ったのですが、こちらの記事を見る限り、今回のケースに使えなさそうだと感じました。
https://elearn.jp/wpman/column/c20110915_01.html

2020/6/20 12:00以降に開始している記事を全て取得したいのですが、対処法をご存知のかたおられませんでしょうか？

該当日時に含まれる投稿が検索されるようにしたいのですが、wp_queryでは限界があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
    $query['meta_query'][] = ['key' => 'end_date', 'value' => array( $date_time, '2999-12-31 00:00' ), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN', 'type' => 'DATE'];
```

指定された日付〜2999-12-31 00:00のBETWEENを取ることで、解決しました。